# Take substring of a string in c

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to take a substring of the string buffer by doing something like the below.  I don't know if it's possible (I've been coding in C for all of about 6 hrs now, but feel free to be as technical as you like, I **think** I can handle it (though I may be wrong))

Edit: I want to take a substring of buffer from the beginning of buffer to the first space.

```
if (buffer[c] == ' ') {
    in_addr_t addr;
    char *ptr = *buffer;
    if(inet_aton("*ptr to *ptr+c", &addr)!=0){
           //do stuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason why strncpy, strncat and the other string functions won't work?  I would answer the question, but it's not clear as to exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: Could you please describe in words what you are trying to accomplish in this code? I just don't get it from the code alone.

Comment: well I suppose I could use them.  Part of the reason I'm asking is that I'm genuinely interested in understanding what I can and cannot do with pointers.

Comment: In your example, you're trying to assign `*buffer` to `ptr`, which should give you warning if it compiles at all; mixing and matching between scalar and pointer types is dangerous at best.

Comment: To get a thorough grounding in low level pointer diddling, read K&R and work the exercises. Really. It is a short book, and very clear (though you have to read it with exacting attention to detail).

Comment: I've ordered it.  It should be here in a week.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strings in c, how to get subString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114377/strings-in-c-how-to-get-substring)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to make one assumption since there are a number of problems with the code:  Assuming that buffer[c] is the first character before the inet address

```
if (buffer[c] == ' ')
{
     in_addr_t addr
     if (inet_aton(&buffer[c+1], &addr))
          // do stuff
}
```

Note:

- `inet_aton` is deprecated since it does not support ipv6.  Use `int inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst);` for forward compatibility.

-- Edit --
To take the substring from the beginning of `buffer` to (but not including) `buffer[c]`, any of these will work:

## 1

```
char buf2 [MAX];
strncpy (buf2, buffer, c);
buf2 [c] = '\000';
```

## 2

```
char buf2 [MAX];
sprintf (buf2, "%.*s", c, buffer);
```

## 3

```
char buf2 [MAX];
int  j;
for (j = 0;  j < c;  ++j)
    buf2 [j] = buffer [j];
buf2 [c] = '\000';
```

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of &buffer[c+1] a little? as I said, I've been using c for about 6 hrs.  

Also, I'm just trying to learn c at the moment so this isn't code that I will ever potentially use, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `&buffer[c+1]` is equivalent to `(buffer + c + 1)`.  It's the address of entry `c + 1` in the array.

Comment: `buffer` is a pointer;  `buffer[c]` is a `char` (presumably).  `buffer[c+1]` is also a char (the one after the space—which I'm assuming is where the inet address text begins—but the function needs a pointer to the first character to process.  The address of `buffer[c+1]` is `&buffer[c+1]`.

Comment: thanks a lot.  I got it working and it feels beautiful.  The only thing that pains me is that I had to artificially  (using a break) exit my for loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify the original buffer, you could just ignore your `ptr` variable and do:

```
if (buffer[c] == ' ') {
    in_addr_t addr;
    buffer[c] = '\0';
    if (inet_aton(buffer, &addr) != 0) {
        // do stuff;
    }
}
```

If you can't modify the original buffer, just use `strncpy()` to copy the part you care about out into a new buffer.

Comment: can I then move the pointer to buffer to the beginning of the new string? like *buffer = *buffer+c or something like that?

Comment: Close; to do that you want `buffer += c + 1`.  The `+1` gets your pointer past the `\0` and to the beginning of the new string.  Be careful that you keep track of the original pointer if it matters (because you might need to `free()` it for example.)

Comment: and keeping track of the old pointer would just be char temp = buffer?

Comment: As an aside, your comment here and the original question seem to show a bit of overuse of the `*` operator; make sure you are understanding the difference between operations on the objects pointed to and operations on the pointers themselves.

Comment: @Mechko, almost.  `char *temp = buffer`.  You need a pointer type to save a copy of a pointer.