# Copying a part of a string (substring) in C

Tags: c

I have a string:

```
char * someString;
```

If I want the first five letters of this string and want to set it to `otherString`, how would I do it?

Comment: someString is not a string, it is a pointer to a string of chars. Also, chars are not necessarily letters. You need to know what a string is before moving letters around.

Comment: Depending on your need its better to declare a char array of size 6 for otherstring( 5 + one byte for '\0'). This way you don't have to care about memory leaks incase you forget to free otherstring after using it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it teaches new users the wrong way to ask, even voting should be disabled.

Comment: Warning: this old question comes with a flood of very bad answers teaching dangerous or incorrect/buggy practice. Some will not even compile. I advise the reader to avoid this post, or otherwise scroll down to the answer I just posted. I also strongly recommend to down vote all the horrible answers, particularly the ones with outright bugs and compiler errors.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
...
char otherString[6]; // note 6, not 5, there's one there for the null terminator
...
strncpy(otherString, someString, 5);
otherString[5] = '\0'; // place the null terminator
```

Comment: Or `otherString[5] = (char)0;` If you want to be picky about it. Char is an integer type, so compilers won't (or shouldn't) complain about just assigning a raw integer to it.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to place the terminating char in single quotes insted of double quotes.

Comment: @pib Unclear about [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114377/strings-in-c-how-to-get-substring#comment2066644_2114388).  Both `otherString[5] = '\0';` and `otherString[5] = 0;`, in C, are assigning an `int` with a value of 0 to a `char`.  So how does `(char)` help in `otherString[5] = (char)0;`?

Comment: This is bad advise. `strncpy` is a dangerous function that should never be used, because way too many people fail to understand how it works. In this case `strncpy` may or may not null terminate the string by itself, depending on the length. It's fickle, unreliable and not originally intended to be used with null terminated strings at all. See [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)

Answer (score 10):

```
char* someString = "abcdedgh";
char* otherString = 0;

otherString = (char*)malloc(5+1);
memcpy(otherString,someString,5);
otherString[5] = 0;
```

**UPDATE**:
**Tip:** A good way to understand definitions is called the right-left rule (some links at the end):

Start reading from identifier and say aloud => "`someString` is..."
Now go to right of someString (statement has ended with a semicolon, nothing to say).
Now go left of identifier (`*` is encountered) => so say "...a pointer to...".
Now go to left of "`*`" (the keyword `char` is found) => say "..char".
Done!

So `char* someString;` => "someString is a pointer to char".

Since a pointer simply points to a certain memory address, it can also be used as the "starting point" for an "array" of characters.

That works with anything .. give it a go:

```
char* s[2]; //=> s is an array of two pointers to char
char** someThing; //=> someThing is a pointer to a pointer to char.
//Note: We look in the brackets first, and then move outward
char (* s)[2]; //=> s is a pointer to an array of two char
```

Some links:
[How to interpret complex C/C++ declarations](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/complex_declarations.aspx) and 
[How To Read C Declarations](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations)

Comment: I think you should try compiling `char *[] someThing;` and `char []* someThing;`.  You want `char *someThing[];` and `char (*someThing)[];` respectively.  And that breaks your algorithm to understand definitions.

Comment: //Thanks, you're right about the bad syntax..fixed the code. However, the algorithm still stands, see the update.

Comment: Don't forget to free after malloc

Comment: `memcpy(someString, otherString, 5);` may have undefined behavior if `someString` has fewer than 4 characters. It works in your example because the source string is longer, but the behavior is not fully defined for small source strings.

Answer (score 10):

Generalized:

```
char* subString (const char* input, int offset, int len, char* dest)
{
  int input_len = strlen (input);

  if (offset + len > input_len)
  {
     return NULL;
  }

  strncpy (dest, input + offset, len);
  return dest;
}

char dest[80];
const char* source = "hello world";

if (subString (source, 0, 5, dest))
{
  printf ("%s\n", dest);
}
```

Comment: it will better if add '\0' at dest[len+1] no?

Comment: There is a subtle bug here; you need to change if(offset + len) to if(offset) otherwise the last characters of the string will never be read; for example:

http://cpp.sh/955ib

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to allocate memory for the new string otherString. In general for a substring of length n, something like this may work for you (don't forget to do bounds checking...)

```
char *subString(char *someString, int n) 
{
   char *new = malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
   strncpy(new, someString, n);
   new[n] = '\0';
   return new;
}
```

This will return a substring of the first n characters of someString. Make sure you free the memory when you are done with it using free().

Comment: please check the malloc return value

Comment: ...or something completely new... `char *new=new char[n+1]` :-)

Comment: `sizeof(char)*n+1` is conceptually wrong.  Could use `sizeof(char)*(n+1)` or simply `n + 1` as `sizeof(char)==1`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use snprintf to get a substring of a char array with precision:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char source[] = "This is a string array";
    char dest[17];

    // get first 16 characters using precision
    snprintf(dest, sizeof(dest), "%.16s", source);

    // print substring
    puts(dest);
} // end main
```

Output:

> This is a string

Note:

For further information see printf man page.

Comment: Not sure what is the cost of this, but the fact of using only one single standard Lib to do this operation, it's kinda remarkable

Answer (score 2):

I had not seen this post until now, the present collection of answers form an orgy of bad advise and compiler errors, only a few recommending `memcpy` are correct. Basically the answer to the question is:

```
someString = allocated_memory; // statically or dynamically
memcpy(someString, otherString, 5);
someString[5] = '\0';
```

This assuming that we know that otherString is at least 5 characters long, then this is the correct answer, period. `memcpy` is faster and safer than `strncpy` and there is no confusion about whether `memcpy` null terminates the string or not - it doesn't, so we definitely have to append the null termination manually.

---

The main problem here is that `strncpy` is a very dangerous function that should not be used for any purpose. The function was never intended to be used for null terminated strings and it's presence in the C standard is a mistake. See [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518), I will quote some relevant parts from that post for convenience:

> Somewhere at the time when Microsoft flagged `strcpy` as obsolete and dangerous, some other misguided rumour started. This nasty rumour said that `strncpy` should be used as a safer version of `strcpy`. Since it takes the size as parameter and it's already part of the C standard lib, so it's portable. This seemed very convenient - spread the word, forget about non-standard `strcpy_s`, lets use `strncpy`! No, this is not a good idea...
>
> Looking at the history of `strncpy`, it goes back to the very earliest days of Unix, where several string formats co-existed. Something called "fixed width strings" existed - they were not null terminated but came with a fixed size stored together with the string. One of the things Dennis Ritchie (the inventor of the C language) wished to avoid when creating C, was to store the size together with arrays [[*The Development of the C Language, Dennis M. Ritchie*](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html)]. Likely in the same spirit as this, the "fixed width strings" were getting phased out over time, in favour for null terminated ones.
>
> The function used to copy these old fixed width strings was named `strncpy`. This is the sole purpose that it was created for. It has no relation to `strcpy`. In particular it was never intended to be some more secure version - computer program security wasn't even invented when these functions were made.
>
> Somehow `strncpy` still made it into the first C standard in 1989. A whole lot of highly questionable functions did - the reason was always backwards compatibility. We can also read the story about `strncpy` in the [C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) 7.21.2.4:
>
> > **The strncpy function**
> > strncpy was initially introduced into the C library to deal with fixed-length name fields in
> > structures such as directory entries. Such fields are not used in the same way as strings: the
> > trailing null is unnecessary for a maximum-length field, and setting trailing bytes for shorter
> > 5 names to null assures efficient field-wise comparisons. strncpy is not by origin a “bounded
> > strcpy,” and the Committee preferred to recognize existing practice rather than alter the function
> > to better suit it to such use.

The Codidact link also contains some examples showing how `strncpy` will fail to terminate a copied string.

**EDIT**

As per C23 we can also copy with `memccpy` (which works exactly like `strncpy` but without the dangerous `str` prefix) and copy + allocate with `strdup`/`strndup`. Some examples using dynamic allocation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
  const char* src = "hello world";

  // copy a sub string of a certain length from the start:
  int length = 5;
  char* str1 = malloc(length+1);
  memccpy(str1, src, '\0', length);
  str1[length] = '\0';
  puts(str1);

  // copy a sub string from an index until the end of the string:
  int from = 6;
  char* str2 = strdup(&src[from]);
  puts(str2);

  // copy a sub string from in between two indices:
  from = 7;
  int to = 10;
  char* str3 = strndup(&src[from], to-from);
  puts(str3);

  free(str1);
  free(str2);
  free(str3);
}
```

Comment: While I agree with your assessment of the answers posted for this question, your recommendation to use `memcpy` is not perfect either: `memcpy(someString, otherString, 5);` may have undefined behavior if `someString` has fewer than 4 characters. There is a simple one liner for this problem: `sprintf(someString, "%.5s", otherString)` but it feels like going grocery shopping with a Sherman tank.

Comment: How do you take substring not from the very beginning with this approach? Say I want to get 5 characters starting from index 3. I know you could add to the otherString a number to make it work. Answer unfortunately doesn't mention that.

Comment: @Phoenix I don't think there's a need to spoon feed every little detail on posts dealing with conceptual stuff. How to do pointer arithmetic and array indexing is very fundamental, beginner-level knowledge.

Comment: @Phoenix I added some examples with the C23 way of doing things, since no post covered those so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat C strings like pointers. So when you declare:

```
char str[10];
```

**str** can be used as a pointer. So if you want to copy just a portion of the string you can use:

```
char str1[24] = "This is a simple string.";
char str2[6];
strncpy(str1 + 10, str2,6);
```

This will copy 6 characters from the **str1** array into **str2** starting at the 11th element.

Comment: Still need to add the null terminator, right?

Comment: You could, but if you're being precise about exactly what bytes you want to copy this way works. Its not dynamic, but it works.

Comment: The OP explicitly wrote: *I want the first five letters*: why do you copy 6 characters and omit the set a null terminator?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easy way... but I don't know how I can pass the result variable directly then I create a local char array as temp and return it.

```
char* substr(char *buff, uint8_t start,uint8_t len, char* substr)
{
    strncpy(substr, buff+start, len);
    substr[len] = 0;
    return substr;
}
```

Comment: `start` and `len` should have type `size_t`, not `uint8_t`

Answer (score -1):

```
strncpy(otherString, someString, 5);
```

Don't forget to allocate memory for otherString.

Comment: Note that this may result in an unterminated string (if `someString` contains five or more characters).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
        char someString[]="abcdedgh";
        char otherString[]="00000";
        memcpy (otherString, someString, 5);
        printf ("someString: %s\notherString: %s\n", someString, otherString);
        return 0;
}
```

You will not need stdio.h if you don't use the printf statement and putting constants in all but the smallest programs is bad form and should be avoided.

Comment: You need to set otherString[5] = '\0' as well

Comment: otherstring after the memcpy is not a valid C string as its not null terminated. After the memcpy you need to add otherstring[5] = '\0';

Comment: Or you can memset(otherstring,'\0',sizeof(otherstring)); before using it.

Comment: That is true, and this illuminates a good issue. Code flexibility should not come at the expense of simplicity. It could ba as simple as char otherString[]="00000"; and thus the null terminating character is a non-issue. The use of '0' instead of '\0' was what prompted my response in the first place, and then I went and forgot it myself...

Comment: This is plain incorrect since you don't null terminate the string nor allocate room for the null terminator.

Answer (score -1):

Doing it all in two fell swoops:

```
char *otherString = strncpy((char*)malloc(6), someString);
otherString[5] = 0;
```

Comment: @pm100 I happen to agree but no one else was, so I figured it was implied.

Comment: Bad advise to use strncpy, see [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518). Additionally you failed to use it correctly so this code will not compile.

Comment: Missing 3rd argument for `strncpy`

Answer (score -1):

```
char largeSrt[] = "123456789-123";  // original string

char * substr;
substr = strchr(largeSrt, '-');     // we save the new string "-123"
int substringLength = strlen(largeSrt) - strlen(substr); // 13-4=9 (bigger string size) - (new string size) 

char *newStr = malloc(sizeof(char) * substringLength + 1);// keep memory free to new string
strncpy(newStr, largeSrt, substringLength); // copy only 9 characters 
newStr[substringLength] = '\0'; // close the new string with final character

printf("newStr=%s\n", newStr);

free(newStr);   // you free the memory
```

Comment: replace strcpy with strncpy otherwise too many arguments error will occur.

Comment: Compile your code before posting it on SO.

Comment: replace strcpy with strncpy: done

Answer (score -2):

**Try this code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

char* substr(const char *src, unsigned int start, unsigned int end);

int main(void)
{
    char *text = "The test string is here";
    char *subtext = substr(text,9,14);

    printf("The original string is: %s\n",text);
    printf("Substring is: %s",subtext);

    return 0;
}

char* substr(const char *src, unsigned int start, unsigned int end)
{
    unsigned int subtext_len = end-start+2;
    char *subtext = malloc(sizeof(char)*subtext_len);

    strncpy(subtext,&src[start],subtext_len-1);
    subtext[subtext_len-1] = '\0';

    return subtext;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).