# Copying from random position Within an array to another array

Tags: c++

I have a char array which contains some value . I want to copy the value from that array from some random index to some other random index . How can I do that ?

```
         #include<iostream.h>
         using namespace std;

         int main()
         {
           char ar[100];
           strcpy(ar,"string is strange");
           cout << ar ;
           return 0;
         }
```

Now ar array contains "string is strange" . Suppose I want to make an another char array `cp` in which I want to copy the value from random index position of `ar` say from 7 to 10 . Is there some string function which we can use ?
I know we can use `strncpy` function but it copies from starting index till number of characters mentioned . Is there some other function or an overloaded version of `strncpy` 
which will enable me to perform the same?

Comment: Homework? Please add tag if so.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114377/198011

Comment: You proably want to upgrade to a compiler which uses `<iostream>`. The `.h` variant is 14 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
strncpy (dest, ar + 7, 2);
```

generally

```
strncpy (destination, source + start_index, number_of_chars);
```

> ```
>    The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied.  Warning: If there
>    is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will  not  be  null-termi‐
>    nated.
> ```

Therefore you need to null terminate the string manually:

```
dest[nos_of_chars] = '\0';
```

**UPDATE**

You can use something like this:

```
char *make_substring (char *src, int start, int end)
{
  int nos_of_chars = end - start + 1;
  char *dest;
  if (nos_of_chars < 0)
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  dest = malloc (sizeof (char) * (nos_of_chars + 1));
  dest[nos_of_chars] = '\0';
  strncpy (dest, src + start, nos_of_chars);
  return dest;
}
```

When you are using C++, do not use the char strings for processing instead use the string class.

Comment: that is not taking from 7-10 that is taking 10 characters from position 7, so it's 7-17.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is in C++, so use the STL - don't create a fixed size character array, use std::string. That has a method substr(pos, n).

so your code would be:

```
std::string str;
str = "string is not so strange";
cout << str << endl;
std::string small;
small = str.substr(7, 3);
cout << small << endl;
```

much easier than doing potentially unsafe pointer arithmetic using the C api.

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy `n` characters starting from position `p` from `string1` to `string2`, you can use:

```
strncpy(string2, string1 + p, n);
```

If you're dealing with C++ strings (`std::string`), then you can use the `substr` member function.

```
std::string string1 = "......";
std::string string2 = string1.substr(p, n);
```

Answer (score 1):

C++

What are you trying to achieve? 'string is strange' reminds me of spell checking -> permutations

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "string is strange";
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());

    while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()))
        std::cout << s << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

To really just exchange random positions: **http://ideone.com/IzDAj**

```
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    mt19937 random;

    string s = "string is strange";
    uniform_int_distribution<size_t> gen(0,s.size()-1);

    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        swap(s[gen(random)], s[gen(random)]);
        cout << s << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the address of a specific place in the array by using e.g. `&ar[i]`.

For example, if you add the following line before the `return`

```
cout << &ar[6] << '\n';
```

it will print

```
is strange
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use memcopy function

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

in your example

```
memcpy(cp,ar+p,sizeof(char)*n)
```