# Displaying pointer substraction

Tags: c, pointers, char, sequence

Okay, say I have a sequence "abcdefg" and I do

```
char* s = strdup("abcdefg");
char* p;
char* q;
p = strchr(s, 'c');// -> cdefg
q = strchr(p, 'd');// -> defg
```

And I want to display `s - p` basically abcdefg - cdefg = ab, can I do this using pointer arithmetic?

Comment: Is modifying `s` an option? You duplicated it, so I suspect that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
printf("%.*s", (int)(p - s), s);
```

This prints `s` with a maximum length of `p - s` which is the number of characters from `s` to `p`.

Comment: Fascinating. I had no idea the percision affected strings like that.

Comment: Is there any chance to save it in a `char*` pointer, something lile: `const char *ptr = (int)(p - s), s;` ?

Comment: @Michi a `char *` points to a character, the only thing you can store in a pointer is the address of a character

Comment: @M.M You right. I really do not know where I was thinking. Probably `sprintf( buf, "%.*s", (int)(p - s), s );`  will do the job. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The string is saved as a sequence of letters ending in a zero byte. If you print a pointer as a string, you will tell it to print the sequence up to the zero byte, which is how you get `cdefg` and `defg`. There is no sequence of bytes that has `'a', 'b', 0` - you would need to copy that into a new char array. `s - p` will simply give you `2` (the distance between the two) - there is no amount of pointer arithmetic that will copy a sequence for you.

To get a substring, see [Strings in C, how to get subString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114377/strings-in-c-how-to-get-substring) - copy with `strncpy`, then place a null terminator.

Comment: M.M said `You can` and you said: `You cannot`. :))

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you need to cut `p` from `s`, the following code should work:

```
char s[100];  // Use static mutable array
strcpy(s, "abcdefg");  // init array (ok, ok I dont remember the syntax how to init arrays)
char* p = strchr(s, 'c');// -> cdefg
*p = 0;  // cut the found substring off from main string
printf("%s\n", s); // -> ab
```