# setting variable to contain part of string in c programming

Tags: c, string, variables

I have a variable str which is "Hello Me".

I want to write a program that will only display the first 5 characters of the string, which is Hello.

Below is a snippet of my code in which I am attempting to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argC, char **argV)
{
        char str[100]="Hello Me";
        char c[100];
        sprintf(c,"%s\n",str[1,4]);
        printf("string is %s\n",str);
}
```

Unfortunately when attempting to do this I got a segmentation fault error.  How do I tweak the program to get the desired results.  I need to display characters like c as an array.

Comment: `str[1,4]` is the same as `str[4]`, which is a single character, not a string. That's the reason for the segfault. To fix it, try `sprintf(c, "%.5s\n", str);`. Of course, you'll have to print `c` in the printf to see the results.

Comment: Now what do I do if I want to start the string off with the second character so it would c would equal ello for example?

Comment: Tip: `char* str = "..."`. Don't bother with the `[100]` unless you need a *mutable* buffer. You an have it auto-sized like `char str[] = "..."`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strings in C, how to get subString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114377/strings-in-c-how-to-get-substring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may build a slice function, which has four inputs, dst string, src string, slice start pos, slice end pos.

Notice the index should be in the range of src string length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
slice_str (char *buffer, char *str, int start, int end)
{
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
    {
      buffer[j++] = str[i];
    }
  buffer[j] = 0;
  return buffer;
}

int
main (void)
{
  char *str = "abcdef";
  int len = strlen (str);
  char ostr[len + 1];
  int start;
  int end;
//index
  start = 1;
  end = 2;
  slice_str (ostr, str, start, end);
//show
  printf ("%s\n--------------\n|index %d to %d|\n--------------\n%s\n", str,
          start, end, ostr);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print only five characters from a string:

```
printf("The first five characters are %.5s\n", the_string);
```

There's no need to copy the string to do that. (Note the difference between the format `%.5s`, which is "if the string argument is longer than five characters, use only the first five.", and `%5s`, which is "if the string is shorter than five characters, first output enough spaces to make the total width five." These two options are independent of each other,, so you can use both: `%7.5s` would be "use at most five characters, and place them at the right-hand side of a seven-character field. If you want to pad on the right instead of the left, use a minus sign.)

In fact, there is much less need to copy strings than you might think. Unnecessary copying is time-consuming and error-prone. It is also surprisingly common. So you should always ask yourself if a copy is really necessary.

If you decide that a copy really is necessary, your first point of call is `strndup`, which dynamically allocates exactly enough storage for a substring of a specified size:

```
char* strndup(const char* original, size_t n);
```

That lets you do things like:

```
char* first_five = strndup(the_string, 5);
```

(If `the_string` only has three characters, for example, that's not a problem. You'll get all three of them.)

Or, if you want a substring from the middle of the string:

```
char* substring = strndup(the_string + start, length);
```

This is not quite as safe, since there is no way that `strndup` can verify that `the_string` has at least `start` characters. To make it safer, you could do this:

```
char* substring = strndup(the_string + strnlen(the_string, start), length);
```

If you really really know that `start` is in range, you don't have to do that. Counting the first `start` characters, which is what `strnlen` does, is not very efficient. But it's better than counting *all* the characters, which is what `strlen` does.

(If you think `the_string + start` looks odd, remember that it is *exactly* the same as `&the_string[start]`; that is, it is the address of element `start` in the array `the_string`.)

You should always use `strndup` if possible, because it's the only moderately standard function which is (reasonably) safe. It's (reasonably) safe because it doesn't depend on your knowing that the destination string is big enough. Unfortunately, it (and `strnlen`) are not yet part of thne C standard (although they're coming soon, I believe), and they were only added to Posix in the 2008 revision. But they've been available for a long time on Linux and for several years now on Mac OS X.

You will need to use the correct feature-test macro, though:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

or

```
 #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
```

That has to go *before any `#include`* in the file which uses the function. If you're using clang or gcc, you can add a `-D` option to your compile command.

If you need Windows compatibility, you'll have to find an open source implementation; fortunately, that's not too hard:

- BSD licence [strndup](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/string/FreeBSD/strndup.c.auto.html)
- BSD licence [strnlen](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/string/FreeBSD/strnlen.c.auto.html)